# What is the worst that could happen connecting the neutral from a smart switch to ground?

Tags: electrical

I have a WeMo wall switch that says I should not install if I do not have a neutral wire. What would be the result if I connected to ground?

Comment: Can you post photos of your situation?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems:

1. Since building codes doesn't allow such usage, any inspector who sees it is going to flag it and likely want to inspect a lot of other wiring.
2. If used in a circuit which is GFCI/RCD protected, any significant current the device would feed through its ground-connected neutral would likely cause the protection device to trip.

I don't think there's any technical reason why it shouldn't be possible for a manufacturer to create a class of switches which would be approved for use in such fashion [ensuring that such switches would never pass more than a fraction of a milliamp through the neutral lead even at startup would require extra circuitry, but that would not be an insurmountable problem.]  I would expect, however, that manufacturers have no motive to build devices which regulators would not recognize, and regulators have no motive to recognize devices that don't exist.

Comment: There are devices (either Lutron or Cooper, IIRC) that have a chassis ground and a return "hybrid" lead that can be tied off to either ground or neutral depending on the application.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Interesting.  I'm in the USA and had not heard of such devices though I've thought they could be helpful in many cases switches don't have neutrals run through them.